# Rust template argument parser seems to be broken

Tags: rust

I am pretty sure a code like this worked before:

```
fn f<F: fn()>(f: F) {
}
```

However, now it gives the following error:

```
error: expected one of `(`, `,`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `for`, lifetime, or path, found `fn`
  --> src/main.rs:96:13
   |
96 |     fn f<F: fn()>(f: F) {
   |            -^^ unexpected token
   |            |
   |            expected one of 8 possible tokens here
```

Note that this compiles fine:

```
fn f(f: fn()) {

}
```

Comment: *code like this worked before* — no, it has never worked in any stable Rust version. I even checked in Rust 1.0.0.

Comment: @Shepmaster yes, i umderstand it after reasing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the [function trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html):

```
fn f<F: Fn()>(f: F) {
}
```

`fn` is a [function pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.fn.html), not a trait.

Note that you can also write this:

```
fn f(f: fn()) {
}
```